# how can I place an "::after" after each div block?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to place an `::after` after each div block in order to say it's the next one with an icon `>` , but however I am not sure how to place. I did as steps::after, but I got below my descript, but I want to add it between each space where my circles will be my `::after` svg icons like the following: [layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CBth8.png)

```
.steps::after{
    content: ">"
}
```

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 steps">
      <div class="icon d-flex">
        <img src="https://code.google.com/images/developers.png" height="80px" />
        <div class="details ml-4 mt-2 text-center">
          <h2>How It Works</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
      <p class="ml-2 mt-3">demo</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 steps">
      <div class="icon d-flex">
        <img src="https://code.google.com/images/developers.png" height="80px" />
        <div class="details ml-4 mt-2 text-center">
          <h2>How It Works</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
      <p class="ml-2 mt-3">demo</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 steps">
      <div class="icon d-flex">
        <img src="https://code.google.com/images/developers.png" height="80px" />
        <div class="details ml-4 mt-2 text-center">
          <h2>How It Works</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
      <p class="ml-2 mt-3">demo</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm confused.  There aren't any divs with the .steps class.  Which divs do you want it applied to?

Comment: woops. I updated the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply specify their absolute position to have them to go to where you want.

```css
.steps::after {
  content: ">";
  position: absolute;
  top: 30%;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 steps">
      <div class="icon d-flex">
        <img src="https://code.google.com/images/developers.png" height="80px" />
        <div class="details ml-4 mt-2 text-center">
          <h2>How It Works</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
      <p class="ml-2 mt-3">demo</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 steps">
      <div class="icon d-flex">
        <img src="https://code.google.com/images/developers.png" height="80px" />
        <div class="details ml-4 mt-2 text-center">
          <h2>How It Works</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
      <p class="ml-2 mt-3">demo</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 steps">
      <div class="icon d-flex">
        <img src="https://code.google.com/images/developers.png" height="80px" />
        <div class="details ml-4 mt-2 text-center">
          <h2>How It Works</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
      <p class="ml-2 mt-3">demo</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```